# adding lots of extensions to magento 2

Tags: magento2

i am kinda new to magento interface. I am using lots of extensions in my store. I was wondering let me know if there are any side effects.Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think side effects no.But your web-site speed make to some slow.And another install are good

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidence.

Comment: i adding answer ??? Do answer accept???

Comment: Yes if u are sure for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a my mind I am not sure,

But I think side effects no. But your web-site speed make to some slow. And another install are good. And second your install extensions some problems so your web-site is Apprehension stop.

Hope this help

Thanks ...